# Deallocate the presenting/previous view controller

Tags: iphone, ios, memory, uiviewcontroller

My app has a login page, then a main page. I want to deallocate the login page when user logs in, and since main page is heavy, I obviously want it to be deallocated when I log out and go to login page again. How to achieve this? I use `presentModalViewController` but I find that memory consumption doesn't decrease on logging out with this method. Will a navigation controller (with `pushViewController` method) do? How to dismiss/deallocate/nil presenting/previous view controller?

Comment: It's not clear what you want to do here. after calling dismissModelViewController memory management is handelled by dealloc.

Comment: Yes, using ARC. But when I do presentModalViewController, memory consumption should decrease very much if I do from a heavy view controller, releasing it, right?

Answer (score 2):

Try tab bar controller with hidden tab bar. Just make one tab - login screen, another - app main screen. When user logged in, just show app screen and then set view controllers of initial tab bar controller to only one vc - main app vc. And be sure you've set all appropriate properties to nil to allow ARC do it's job and dealloc the login screen.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve with this code:

```
MainViewController *mainController = [MainViewController new];
UIWindow *mainWindow = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows] firstObject];
[mainWindow.rootViewController removeFromParentViewController];
[mainWindow setRootViewController:mainController];
```

Answer (score 0):

View controller use the concept of a stack, so you have to have a root view controller to handle the switching. Have one master view controller that is basically blank, and add your two other view controllers to it as needed.